# How to best use OOP principles to deal with a case of having 10-15+ matching criteria that all need to be passed?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that takes in lines of text and uses about 15 different "criteria" (individual preg_match statements) to check if the line should qualify to be saved in an array.

How does one best handle such a situation with clean, maintainable code?

Initially I had a crazy long if statement which had all the criteria, for example:

```
if (
    preg_match($criteria1,$line) &&
    preg_match($criteria2, $line) &&
    ...
    ...
    ...
    preg_match($criteriaN,$line)
) {
    //do something, e.g. save the line to an array.
}
```

I've since put each preg_match statement into a different function within a separate class and call each function in a row, checking if it's true... But now I have 15 separate functions that are only subtly different from each other and it still doesn't feel like I'm writing good code. How is it best to handle this situation?

Comment: Get all criteria in a list/array, then loop that list and call `preg_match` in each iteration passing the regular expression.

Comment: OOP? A CriteriaCollection of Criteria classes with both a `valid($input)` method?

Comment: 15 regexes sounds an awful lot. Could any of these regexes be replaced by a filter_var() check I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to keep things object oriented, you could use a class like this...

```
class Validator{

    /* Any criteria needing to be met must exist in this array */
    public static $criterias = array($criteria1,
                                      $criteria2,
                                      ... ,
                                      $criteriaN);



    public static function validate($line){

        /* Make sure this line meets each criteria */
        foreach(Validator::$criterias as $criteria){

              if(!preg_match($criteria, $line))
                   return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It makes sense to have the methods and properties static because they are unique to no instance.  Then you can simply check to see if a line meets the criteria by calling

```
Validator::validate($line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
$rgCriterias = [$sCriteria0, $sCriteria1, $sCriteria2];
if(!count(array_filter($rgCriterias, function($sCriteria) use ($line)
{
   return !preg_match($sCriteria, $line);
})))
{
   //do the stuff
}
```

Comment: "How to best use **OOP** principles to deal with..."

Comment: OOP and that case are not linked - in general. I think code above will fit to topic starter's requirements. Let's say we encapsulate check into closure ("OOP style").

Answer (score 0):

Might be an overkill, but you can use the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). a very simplified example would be:

```
abstract class Specification
{
    abstract public function isSatisfiedBy($obj);
}

class RegExSpecification extends Specification
{
    private $_pattern;

    public function __construct($pattern)
    {
        $this->_pattern = $pattern;
    }

    public function isSatisfiedBy($obj)
    {
        return preg_match($this->_pattern, $obj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class YourLinesProcessor
{
     private $_specs;

     public function setSpecs($specs)
     {
         $this->_specs = $specs;
     }

     public function check($line)
     {
           foreach ($this->_specs as $spec)
                $satisfied = $spec->isSatisfiedBy($line);

           if ($satisfied)
               // do something
     }
}

$specs = array();
$specs[] = new RegExSpecification("\some\pattern");
$specs[] = new RegExSpecification("\another\pattern");

$processor = new YourLinesProcessor();
$processor->setSpecs($specs);
$processor->check("line_data");
```